# Where can we found the source code of iOS agent for EMM 2.0.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

In the source code of emm version 2.0.0 https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm, we found the source code of android and windows phone agent.

Where can we found that for iOS agent ?

Comment: Not a programming / development question. SO is not a directory operator to find things for you.

Comment: iOS agent code has some proprietary licence. So that code repository has not exposed to outside.

Answer (score 1):

The repository for iOS is a private repository which has been exposed only to internal developers since it contains proprietary content.

Windows Phone Agent is an inbuilt system app called "[Workplace](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/accounts-and-billing/set-up-or-delete-a-workplace-account)" shipped by Microsoft itself. What you have found in the [product-mdm](https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm) repository is a part of the Windows server side source code, not the agent source code.